Help identifying a film featuring a rich bad boy?
A couple years back I happened to catch the beginning of a film that really interested me but was unable to finish or find out the name. It looked fairly new probably no older than 2000. It featured a Largo Winch type character as the main protagonist, a heir to a large corporation that he does not want to associate himself with. It begins with him stealing a prototype phone plan and releasing it on the internet. When confronted he says that the  plan belonged to the people or something along those lines. Hope thats enough information. 

Do you know the country of origin?  Language?  Anything else about it that could help narrow it down?

It was in English wouldn't know which country though

That part sort of matches the beginning of Tron: Legacy. In the beginning of that movie, the protagonist sneaks into the company his father built and hacks into its network, disrupting a meeting about a new operating system that the company is about to release. He reveals to the current CEO that he has stolen the OS and has released it for free on the web. 


I would say more than sort of considering the only different is the phone vs OS.

First movie I thought of as well.

I'm pretty sure this is correct as well ... First thing I thought of as well.
